# UILabel error - [__NSCFNumber string]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uilabel

I am getting this error sort of randomly. It doesn't always happen but regardless, it doesn't make sense.

"[__NSCFNumber string]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

shows up on this line:

```
_displayLabel.text = @"";
```

`_displayLabel` is an iVar of type `UILabel` and I am simply clearing the text from it here. Where is this `NSCFNumber` coming from? Is this an improper way of clearing the text from a `UILabel`?

Note: This is an ARC project.

**UPDATE**

I am getting a different error involving the same object in a different part of my code, again pretty randomly. Sometimes I see it, others I don't

```
-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString string]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I am seeing at this line

```
NSLog(@"displayLabel: %@", _displayLabel.text);
```

I'll reiterate that this is an ARC project and I have no `release` messages anywhere in my code. Could it be that ARC has inserted them poorly?

Comment: In short: the variable you think is a label is actually a pointer to something else (in this case a NSNumber) and you problem lies elsewhere where you are still referencing the object after it was changed.

Comment: Unless you find an obvious mistake where you assign an `NSNumber` to your `UILabel` variable, this is most likely the result of memory mismanagement. You probably overreleased the label and the memory just happens to have an `NSNumber` object in its place.

Comment: Right, there is no obvious mis-assignment. As I said, this is an ARC project so could it be that the compiler has incorrectly inserted releases for this object?

Comment: @Kevin_TA: It's very unlikely that it's the compiler's fault. Do you use any external frameworks or CoreFoundation objects that you've bridged to ARC using the `__bridged*` keywords?

Comment: How is the `_displayLabel` ivar defined? Is it from a property? Is the property defined with `strong`?

Comment: my guess as i've lost 2hours today is: is there any dictionary in your class where you could ask for the wrong key? The shown error is not always the where the error is.

Comment: The issue is old but I have encountered the same error described in first question and in UPDATE of it in non-ARC project with subclass of label which changes its value very frequently. Generally it works fine but sometimes it crashes in very strange way.